# scatter plot not respecting adaptive sampling with scatter style ssDot

Tags: c++, qt5, qcustomplot

For a performance evaluation I was plotting the same data, with `QCPScatterStyle::ssCircle` and `QCPScatterStyle::ssDot`, both with adaptive sampling disabled. The graph with `ssCircle` looks good, and is a bit slothy, but that was expected, while the graph with `ssDot` is faster, which was also expected, but the graph looks way too thin (not expected) and the data changes appearance while resizing (not expected).

[image]

The right images are after a minimal change of width. The top is using `ssDot`, the bottom is using `ssCircle`. As can be seen, there is a visible difference between the top two graphs.

Am I doing something wrong, is this a bug, or is this possibly even the intended behavior?

This is using QCustomPlot 2.0.1 with MSVC 2017 on Win10.

```
#include <random>

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>

#include <qcustomplot.h>

int
main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  QApplication app( argc, argv );
  QMainWindow wnd;

  auto *customPlot = new QCustomPlot();
  customPlot->addGraph();

  std::normal_distribution<> d{5, 2};
  std::random_device rd{};
  std::mt19937 gen{rd()};

  int const num = 100000;

  QVector<double> x0, y0;
  x0.resize( num );
  y0.resize( num );

  for( int n = 0; n < num; ++n ) {
    x0[n] = d( gen );
    y0[n] = d( gen );
  };

  customPlot->graph( 0 )->setScatterStyle(
      QCPScatterStyle( QCPScatterStyle::ssCircle, 1 ) );
  //      QCPScatterStyle( QCPScatterStyle::ssDot, 1 ) );
  customPlot->graph( 0 )->setLineStyle( QCPGraph::lsNone );
  customPlot->graph( 0 )->setAdaptiveSampling( false );
  customPlot->graph( 0 )->setData( x0, y0 );

  customPlot->xAxis->setRange( -5, 15.0 );
  customPlot->yAxis->setRange( -5, 15.0 );

  wnd.setCentralWidget( customPlot );
  wnd.resize( 400, 300 );
  wnd.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I tracked down the cause of the problem. To me it looks like a bug. I changed it to work the way that I expect by switching from `drawLine` to `drawPoint`

```
void QCPScatterStyle::drawShape(QCPPainter *painter, double x, double y) const
{
    ...
    case ssDot:
    {
      //painter->drawLine(QPointF(x, y), QPointF(x+0.0001, y));
      painter->drawPoint(QPointF(x, y));
      break;
    }
    ...
}
```